# How I make persistent network interface changes programmatically?

Tags: debian

I am running Debian Wheezy on an embedded platform (Beaglebone-variant) and want to allow users to make persistent changes to a network interface - e.g., change from static to DHCP or add a gateway. Once they make the change, I want it to be able to survive a reboot, so that it comes up with the last made change selected by the user.

Since users will change this via a web-served UI, I want to make the changes programmatically. I was thinking of generating a new 'interfaces' file and replacing the existing /etc/network/interaces file (then forcing a reboot), but was wondering if there a less intrusive way of doing this, for example, through the command line or other programmatic method. While my onboard server code has all the information needed to generate a replacement /etc/network/interfaces file, I worry that any errors I run into could break the interfaces file and effectively brick the system for the user. Hence my question for a less intrusive way of doing this.

This is what our current factory setting 'interfaces' file looks like:

```
# loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.168.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:10

#secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:11
```

Comment: You can [use augeas](http://blog.bigon.be/2011/05/16/managing-etcnetworkinterfaces-with-puppet-and-augeas/) That's puppet-centric but there are similar commands you can run using either `augtool` or the API. Augeas is generally pretty good about being non-intrusive, it'll even keep the whitespace the same as it was before. Nothing gets regenerated, just modified in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit damage by separating the fixed and variable parts via the `source` keyword in your main `interfaces` file. Unfortunately, `source-directory` is not available in wheezy.